# Proving a stochastic process is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $I_t=\max_{0\leq s \leq t} B_s$. 
I need to prove that the following is a martingale:
$$M_t = \int_0^t [-2(I_s-B_s) + 4B_s^3] dB_s$$
From a previous question, $M_t$ is a continuous local martingale so it is a martingale if
$$\mathbb{E} (M_t^2) < \infty$$
So I need to show that
$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t [4(I_s-B_s)^2 - 16B_s^3(I_s-B_s) + 16B_s^6] ds \right)< \infty$$
This can be separated to three expectations but I am not sure how to find 
$$4\mathbb{E} ((I_s-B_s)^2)$$
and $$16\mathbb{E} (B_s^3(I_s-B_s))$$